# I have 125KHz RFID Reader, why it fails to read more than one tag at a time? how to program it for reading multiple tags?

Tags: rfid

I have 125KHz RFID Reader. Why does it fail to read more than one tag at a time? How can I program it for reading multiple tags? Is it possible to add an anticollision protocol there?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not using a reader and tag that is capable of anti-collision protocol.  Without that capability the tags answer at the same time and interfere with each other's signals.

Anti-collision is not common with LF RFID.